# How to convert special java interface to pascal interface?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have those 2 interfaces

```
public interface TransferListener<S> {
  ...
}

public interface BandwidthMeter {
 ...
}
```

and this implementation :

```
public final class DefaultBandwidthMeter implements BandwidthMeter, TransferListener<Object> {
  ....
}
```

How can i **declare the pascal version** of DefaultBandwidthMeter ?

Right now i declare it like this :

```
  JDefaultBandwidthMeterClass = interface(JBandwidthMeterClass)
    ['{2B9F65F5-8EAB-466A-9A2E-DDD9CA88F807}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultBandwidthMeter')]
  JDefaultBandwidthMeter = interface(JBandwidthMeter)
    ['{D6A32707-D8F6-458B-AAB6-926A523D1A95}']
  end;
  TJDefaultBandwidthMeter = class(TJavaGenericImport<JDefaultBandwidthMeterClass, JDefaultBandwidthMeter>) end;
```

But the problem is that this declaration don't care about TransferListener and will not work with function like:

```
public DefaultDataSourceFactory(TransferListener<? super DataSource> listener) { 
  ...
}
```

So how can i do ?

Comment: Once you obtain an instance of the actual `DefaultBandwidthMeter` class, it still implements `BandwidthMeter` and `TransferListener<Object>` on the Java side, if not on the Delphi side. So, you should be able to query the object for its `TransferListener` interface before passing it to `DefaultDataSourceFactory()`. You will probably have to use JNI to call Java's `Class.cast()` method, or use Java's Reflection API, to get the actual interface reference, and then `Wrap()` it with a corresponding Delphi JNI wrapper interface. Sorry, I don't have any code samples to share.

Comment: Thanks remy it's this ! simply do a DefaultDataSourceFactory(TJTransferListener.Wrap(fbandwidthMeter)) and it's does the trick ! You can write the answer and I will accept it, it's could be usefull for other i guess

Comment: feel free to post and accept your own answer if you want to share your finding